# pc and laptop not visible on local network - trying to use python http server to connect a laptop to a pc

Tags: networking, server, python

I have been trying to set up a local HTTP server using python in order to connect a laptop and a desktop pc but with no success. Both of them are connected to the home router, the desktop via a cable and the laptop via the wi-fi. Up-to-date Ubuntu 18.04 runs on both machines.

I tried pretty much every tip I could find: disabled ufw on both computers, tried with python2 vs python3 etc. After I set up the server I can connect succesfully from mozilla firefox on the server machine, therefore I know the port is served correctly. I tried connecting using the ip from ifconfig, using a bind or localhost:port but all work only on the local machine and not on the laptop. I have used commands like: `python3 -m http.server 8080 --bind 127.0.0.1` `python3 -m http.server 8080` `python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8080` but without any differences as I still can't connect from the laptop. Also tried using the laptop as a server, does not work.

I fiddled with options on the router but with no success whatsoever.

I also tried using samba to connect and I observed *the server is visible on the laptop and vice versa, so they "see each other" in nautilus,* but cannot connect. Also tried using various tools such as woof or fileserve without working.

What else can I do?

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks!

========

I will add a screenshot to better describe the situation

[the samba server is visible on both computers so I know the computers communicate in a way](https://i.stack.imgur.com/exhQ9.png)

I think Python will be the way to go since it is much simpler, I abandoned samba

given that I cannot connect the two pcs in neither way makes me wonder if there is any modification I could do to router settings, yet again, the router interface is quite simple and I tried to change some of them but no changes were observed

Edit: I tried using nmap to see all IPs connected to the router, this is what I get on the PC:

```
daniel@daniel:~$ nmap -sP 192.168.1.0/24

Starting Nmap 7.60 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2020-04-18 12:18 EEST
Nmap scan report for _gateway (192.168.1.1)
Host is up (0.00051s latency).
Nmap scan report for daniel (192.168.1.2)
Host is up (0.000093s latency).
Nmap done: 256 IP addresses (2 hosts up) scanned in 3.02 seconds
```

192.168.1.1 is the router and 192.168.1.2 is the PC; when I run the command on the laptop I get 192.168.1.1 and 192.168.1.3 as expected however there is something blocking the two computers from communicating and also blocking the http probably, although it is something that does not prevent the samba server to be visible on both host and remote computers.

In other words, the initial problem *could* be tractable to the computers not seeing each other on local network.

But why?

What could it be? What other checks can I do to see why the simple http server does not work?

PLUS: following output on the PC:

```
daniel@daniel:~$ sudo ufw verbose
Status: inactive
daniel@daniel:~$ systemctl status firewalld
Unit firewalld.service could not be found.
daniel@daniel:~$ nmap 192.168.1.2 -p1-255

Starting Nmap 7.60 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2020-04-18 18:54 EEST
Nmap scan report for daniel (192.168.1.2)
Host is up (0.000069s latency).
All 255 scanned ports on daniel (192.168.1.2) are closed

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.03 seconds
```

when i run the command `nmap 192.168.1.2 -p1-255` on the laptop is says "Host seems down"

Comment: Please don't post scrennshots of the text in the terminal. Please copy and paste the text directly into your question and format it as `code` using the { } icon above the edit window.

Comment: Silly question, `firewalld` isn't being used over `ufw` is it? Also, try a port scan as well as opposed to just ICMP: `nmap 192.168.1.2 -p1-255`

Comment: I stopped the service `firewalld` on both computers and edited the question, i guess this is what you mean? Nevertheless, there was nothing to stop, as the service was not installed? Does not fix the problem yet. Indeed i'm not an expert.

Comment: @Daniel - sorry, `192.168.1.2` is the IP of the host you want to scan. So from your PC you're scanning the other to see what ports you have open. Also, does `sudo firewalld stop` do anything?

Comment: @DankyNanky PC's IP is 192.168.1.2 and laptop's IP is 192.168.1.3, took them from `ifconfig`. So I just ran the command `nmap 192.168.1.3 -p1-255` from the PC but got "host seems down". Output of `sudo firewalld stop` was `firewalld: error: unrecognized arguments: stop`.

Comment: "Host seems down" stipulates a network connection issue. ICMP from Laptop <-> PC is successful, right? If the Firewall (`ufw` or `firewalld`) are disabled on both devices then inter-connectivity is determined by the router/switch and the network you're on.  Re-reading your question I note you can inter-connect between the two; but, if your router doesn't do any filtration we *should* be good (you could try a mock `iperf` test between the two as another example). I'm going to stop here though, leave it to the experts to correct us :)

Comment: thank you for your efforts! appreciate it! Indeed it is weird that when I open the samba server it is visible on the other computer, although can't connect. It does seem like it has to do with the router settings, but I tried changing most of them, no results. I will try to use iperf to see what happens.